# In batch file, how to get focus on a specific window (opened file)

Tags: vba, batch-file, focus

A very simple question I suppose, but I reached a deadlock with this:

I have to use a .bat file to imput plain text data into the right cells an excel sheet with lots of graphics content, vba parts, macro that deactivate "normal" EXCEL buttons and functions, password to protect the pre-typed functions, sudden and unexpected changes in the version of the "taget file", and many other complications...

My need is to be absolutely sure that the .bat is sending the sequence into the right version of the .xlsm file.

To do that I want to store the last known filename (that include the file version) in the .bat file, and I want to take focus on the excel window in wich the data have to be written ONLY IF the title of the excel window is exactly the same.

So Here is the question: How to get the focus on a specific open file from a .bat file?

Comment: Please don't scream. :(

Comment: Sorry for the upper case... it was to "underline" the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you wanted to use vbscript or jscript you could do what you want in a command prompt in an unreliable way (but it will work most circumstances).

Excel has it's own forms.

Put column headers in a row. Put selection in same row. **Alt + D, O**.

Plus you can make Excel only allow entries on some cells, like a invoice form.

Right click cell, Properties, Protection, Unlock. Then **Alt + T, P, P**.

Word has it's own forms similar to Excel (Word is also a spreadsheet).

Excel VBA language (and VBScript too) has input box command.

```
Sub main()
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value2 = InputBox("enter Value")
End Sub
```